# Creating A Simple Login System as a personal project and having some issues with IO in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My question is that I am creating a login system in python. This system is very simple. The user type login , his email and password. The program checks from a file whether the email or password is correct or not. But I am running into some issues with that. So I first opened the file then asked the user if he wants to log in or signup. If he types login the program asks for email and password and check in the file whether this matches or not. The program takes input correctly but at the time of checking it fails. It does not give an error but it does not print the desired statement. This my code

```
with open('Data_Login_System.txt' , 'r') as data:
    user_input = input("""Type Either Login or SignUp> """)
    if user_input.lower() == "login":
        Email = input("""Type your Email> """)
        Password = input("""Type Your Password> """)
        for line in data:
           if line.lower() == f"email : {Email.lower()}" or line.lower() == f"password : {Password.lower()}":
               print("Logged in")
```

These are the contents of the file.

```
Email : shabeebasghar123@gmail.com
Password : shabeebasghar123
```

Whenever I enter the correct email and password it should print logged in but it does not the program just run finely and nothing at the end
This is the execution of the program

```
Type Either Login or SignUp
> login
Type your Email
> shabeebasghar123@gmail.com
Type Your Password
> shabeebasghar123
```

Comment: The lines from the file have an end of line character (`'\n'`) at the end...

Comment: I get `logged in` as output without modifying single line of your code. Maybe you have mispelled something or maybe your text file fomat is inappropriate

Comment: Unrelated to your question; Why not use a proper / lite database?  Surely the returned value from a query (password, for example) will be easier to test than parsing / searching a text file.  Just a thought ...

Comment: @Karthik I have tried it many times but it does not work.

Comment: If your `print` call isn't executing it's because your `if` condition is never true. Try `line.lower().strip()`. If that isn't the problem print out both values in an `else` clause and compare the 2 strings carefully by eye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by just doing `line.lower().strip()` intead of just `line.lower()`

Answer (score -1):

First of all you got to use a readlines() function to read lines from the .txt file with a loop. You could actually read a lines without a loop on that one. See code below.

```
lines = data.readlines()
print(data)
```

The out put for that would be:
['Email : mail@gmail.com\n', 'Password : passwd123'].

So I would try a bit different approach. Make sure that you don't have any unwanted extra lines in txt file.

```
user_input = input("Type Either Login or SignUp")
if user_input.lower() == "login":
    email = input("""Type your Email""")
    password = input("""Type Your Password""")

    with open("data.txt", 'r') as f:
        t_mail = f.readline()
        t_passwd = f.readline()
        if f"Email : {email}\n" == t_mail and f"Password : {password}" == t_passwd:
            print('You are now logged in')
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: This gives me a list after iterating over it and checking the email in the same way above it gives me the same output

Comment: See my post. Is this answer your question?

Comment: I still get the same output. It works fine but in the end, the code execution ends without printing logged in. This is the screenshot of the output [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bv6xYJ_sXelrNZrVkZy5KFYzkA2a-_gm/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: can you make a screenshot of your code and contents of .txt file in IDE and show it?